# HA RabbitMQ without set mirror policy

Tags: rabbitmq

I set up lab about ha for rabbitmq using cluster and mirror queue. 
I am using centos 7 and rabbitmq-server 3.3.5. with three server (ha1, ha2, ha3).

I have just joined ha1 and ha2 to ha3, but do not set policy for mirror queue. When I test create queue with name "hello" on ha1 server, after i check on ha2, and ha3 using rabbitmqctl list queue, hello queue is exist on all node on cluster.

I have a question, why i do not set policy to mirror queue on cluster, but it automatic mirror queue have been created on any node on cluster?

Please give me advice about I have mistake or only join node on cluster, queue will be mirror on all node of cluster. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rabbitmq , by default, one queue is stored only to one node. When you create a cluster, the queue is available  across nodes.

But It does't mean that the queue is mirrored, if the node gets down the queue is marked as down and you can't access.

Suppose to create one queue to the node, the queue will work until the node is up, as:

[image]

if the node is down you will have:

[image]

you should always apply the mirror policy, otherwise you could lose the messages

Comment: Yes, thank pro. I forget test when down master cluster that created queue. queue will be delete on all clusters when master's queue cluster was down

Comment: you are welcome, I suggest to update to the version `3.6.1` you are using an old version. if you think the answer is correct, please accept. @SơnLâm