# Is a queue from RabbitMQ cluster physically dedicated to one server?

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing

Just like mentioned in title, when a queue is declared on a server amongst a group of nodes which are all in a cluster, is it physically on a single server? or physically spread over nodes and considered logically on a server?

Comment: please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328510/ha-rabbitmq-without-set-mirror-policy/36328889#36328889

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from [rabbitmq docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html)

> All data/state required for the operation of a RabbitMQ broker is
>   replicated across all nodes. An **exception to this are message
>   queues**, which by default reside on one node, though they are visible
>   and reachable from all nodes.

So unless the queues are mirrored, they are on one node (for mirroring queues see [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html)).

Comment: Thanks guys. After reading the official document (like what you pasted for me above), I've known that a queue resides on a node even though nodes are clustered (sometimes clustering includes ha too, right?). Still, my co-workers (they aren't on rabbitmq related projects) suspected that a queue is dedicated to one node. So I wanted to make sure unless they are mirrored queues could be lost on a server fail.

Comment: You are welcome! According to this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79347/reminding-new-users-of-accept-upvote-duty I wouldn't be too bad if I ask that if my answer answers your question that you accept it and/or upvote it.